# converting regex to sed or grep regex

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am not sure why this doesn't work. Here is the regex `'text\' => '.*?'` and I want to catch `estrenos` and `cine` in the following nasty text using grep or sed. Here is what I tried in grep

```
echo "sadsa d{                             'text' => 'cine',                             'indices' => [                                            111,                                            116                                          ]                           },                           {                             'text' => 'estrenos',                             'indices' => [ sSADW" | grep -Eo "'text\' => '.*?',"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='}' -F\' '{print $4}' file
cine
estrenos
```

That will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box. It will also work no matter what the white space is so it'll work whether your input is on one line or spread across multiple lines and no matter how many blanks or tabs occur anywhere on each line.

Here's how it works:

awk treats all input as records separated into fields. Your input (with spaces compressed for readability):

```
sadsa d{ 'text' => 'cine', 'indices' => [ 111, 116 ] }, { 'text' => 'estrenos', 'indices' => [ sSADW
```

clearly has `{ ... }` records:

Record 1:

```
{ 'text' => 'cine', 'indices' => [ 111, 116 ] }
```

Record 2:

```
{ 'text' => 'estrenos', 'indices' => [ sSADW
```

so we can set the Record Separator to `}` (with `-v RS='}'`). I assume your last record will really end in a `}` too but if it doesn't that's fine as awk treats end of file like the end of a record. We can ignore the text before the `{`s (i.e. "sadsa d" before the first record and "," between the 2 records - that's really treated as part of the first field but we're not using that field for anything so it's irrelevant.

So given the above 2 records if we split them into fields at every `'` (with `-F\'`) then we get:

```
$ awk -v RS='}' -F\' '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) print "Record Nr", NR, "Field Nr", i, "Field Contents: <" $i ">"; print "----"
}' file
Record Nr 1 Field Nr 1 Field Contents: <sadsa d{ >
Record Nr 1 Field Nr 2 Field Contents: <text>
Record Nr 1 Field Nr 3 Field Contents: < => >
Record Nr 1 Field Nr 4 Field Contents: <cine>
Record Nr 1 Field Nr 5 Field Contents: <, >
Record Nr 1 Field Nr 6 Field Contents: <indices>
Record Nr 1 Field Nr 7 Field Contents: < => [ 111, 116 ] >
----
Record Nr 2 Field Nr 1 Field Contents: <, { >
Record Nr 2 Field Nr 2 Field Contents: <text>
Record Nr 2 Field Nr 3 Field Contents: < => >
Record Nr 2 Field Nr 4 Field Contents: <estrenos>
Record Nr 2 Field Nr 5 Field Contents: <, >
Record Nr 2 Field Nr 6 Field Contents: <indices>
Record Nr 2 Field Nr 7 Field Contents: < => [ sSADW
>
----
```

so as you can see the value you want is always simply the 4th field of each record.

Comment: Could you please break it down?

Comment: I added an explanation, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: hell of an explanation. too good. And Ed, don't you think using extended grep would be a good option as well, as grep is primarily made for this purpose. Here for eg. `egrep -o "'text' => '\w+'" file | cut -d\' -f4` ? If not, why ?

Comment: 1) `-o` and `\w` are both non-POSIX grep extensions (maybe GNU-only, idk) so YMMV with using them. 2) I suspect the OP might want to extend this to print other fields under other situations and the awk is easily extensible to do whatever she wants, 3) The awk script will not fail if the input is all on one huge line since it reads it one `}`-separated chunk at a time instead of one line at a time, idk what the grep would do, 4) the awk script is more concise than 2 tools plus a pipe, 5) the awk script doesn't rely on input data values, just it's relative position.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the escaping character for the single quote. However, since the extended regexp doesn't support non-greedy matching you probably want to use Perl instead:

```
grep -Po "'text' => '.*?',
```

Comment: Nice! But, this returns `'text' => 'cine'`, but I want to get `cine`

Comment: @user3639557 you can modify that to `grep -Po "'text' => '\K[^']+"` or `grep -Po "'text' => '\K[^']+(?=',)"` for robustness

Comment: You should mention that's GNU grep only and that according to the GNU grep man page `-P` is "highly experimental" so YMMV with using it.

Answer (score 0):

**tr** + **sed** approach:

(assuming your input text is in variable `$s`)

```
sed -n "s/.*'text' => '\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$s")
```

The output:

```
cine
estrenos
```