# sed - extract data between 2 words from different parts of .txt by combining 3 sed commands

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have multiple .txt with info like this:

```
"commercial_name":"THE OUTBACK","contact_name":"JEFF","contact_person":"MANAGER","working_place"
```

there is a lot of garbage behind and after the given sentence.
I want to get results like this:

```
THE OUTBACK,JEFF,MANAGER
```

All in the same line for each .txt file, but jump line for the next .txt.

I am doing with 3 different sed commands

```
sed -n 's:.*"commercial_name"\(.*\)"contact_name".*:\1:p' *.txt

sed -n 's:.*"contact_name"\(.*\)"contact_person".*:\1:p' *.txt

sed -n 's:.*"contact_person"\(.*\)"working_place".*:\1:p' *.txt
```

even if I combine these 3, the result is:

```
:"THE OUTBACK",
```

-all commercial names 1 line for each .txt

```
:"JEFF",
```

-all contact names 1 line for each .txt

```
:"MANAGER",
```

-all contact person 1 line for each .txt

I want to extract all the info in the same line:

```
THE OUTBACK,JEFF,MANAGER
```

then the info for the next .txt in the next line
and so on.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please do add your input and output in code tags in correct form(how they actually look alike) so that we could better understand the question, thank you.

Comment: For extracting json use json-aware tools like `jq`

Comment: it's not json, but thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
   gsub(/"/, "")
   for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      if (split($i, entry, ":") == 2)
         map[entry[1]] = entry[2]
   }
   print map["commercial_name"], map["contact_name"], map["contact_person"]
}' file
```

```
THE OUTBACK,JEFF,MANAGER
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, partially. when I use your awk the result is:  14 times double comma like this: ,,  and then 20 times THE OUTBACK,JEFF,MANAGER. I'm still looking the way to reduce duplicates. BIG thanks for your help!

Comment: If you show your bigger sample data then I can check why double commas are showing.

Comment: I resolved the issue applying | uniq to your awk. Now it returns uniq lines. BIG thank you anubhava!

Comment: How could I initialize map, after: print map["commercial_name"], map["contact_name"], map["contact_person"] ? because if one file does not contain any of these 3 map, is printing in the next line, example: file 1 contains commercial_name, contact_name and contact_person, but file 2 have commercial_name, contact_person... so in this line 2 is printing the contact_name from line 1.

Comment: You can just use `delete map` after print statement.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

1. we set `FS` and `OFS` separately:

```
awk -v FS=',|:' -v OFS=',' '{print $2,$4,$6}'  file
"THE OUTBACK","JEFF","MANAGER"
```

2. and `gsub` for removing double quotes:

```
awk -v FS=',|:' -v OFS=',' '{gsub(/"/, "")} {print $2,$4,$6}'  file
THE OUTBACK,JEFF,MANAGER
```

This code:

- why printing `$2,$4,$6`?

[Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) gives a detail explication here:
[converting regex to sed or grep regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142118/converting-regex-to-sed-or-grep-regex)

- Using Ed's code, you can see it with `for`

```
awk -v FS=',|:' -v OFS=',' '{gsub(/"/, "")} {for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) print "Record", NR, "Field", i, ":  " $i;}{print  RT}'  file
Record,1,Field,1,:  commercial_name
Record,1,Field,2,:  THE OUTBACK
Record,1,Field,3,:  contact_name
Record,1,Field,4,:  JEFF
Record,1,Field,5,:  contact_person
Record,1,Field,6,:  MANAGER
Record,1,Field,7,:  working_place
```

- In this case, we are interested in fields 2, 4 and 6:

`{print $2,$4,$6}`

--

Comment: Hi, Carlos, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately files has garbage before and after the given data. So fields 2,4 and 6 are not what you are pointing to.

Comment: Yes, its a solution only for the shown data of the input.